# Witch spawn areas for already generated worlds in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a large explored area in a pre "Pretty Scary Update" world.  Including several swamp areas.  Will witches spawn in those areas?  If so, is there a stand alone tool (like this one for slimes:  http://mcslimes.appspot.com/ ) or similar for finding witch spawn areas?

Comment: If the swap areas is generated before the update, then no, witch will not spawn.

Comment: Are there any swamp huts there? If yes, then witches will spawn there. If not, you could go to single-player, select the world, and then press re-generate to re-generate the world again (as a different save). This will use the same seed, so the swamp huts will be there in the re-generated world save.

Comment: @JeffreyLin does doing such a thing erase anything I've done to my world?

Comment: @w1nger1 do you have a reference for that?  I've read inconclusive reports on this.

Comment: @Ender no, it does not. As stated above, the world generator will create a new map with the same seed, so there are going to be swamp huts in your new save. Your old stuff will still be in your old save, untouched.

Comment: @John This is how the Minecraft map generate mechanism works. It will not alter anything that is already generated.

Comment: @Ender If you are looking to bring buildings and items to a new map. No you can't do that in game, you need a 3rd party program to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are there any swamp huts there?

If yes, then witches will spawn there.

If not, you could go to single-player, select the world, and then press re-generate to re-generate the world again (as a different save). This will use the same seed, so the swamp huts will be there in the re-generated world. Your inventory and world will still be in your old save.

Your third option is to port them over using MCEdit, a third-party program used to customize your world.

Comment: Unless the map was generated with snapshots, there won't be any Swamp Huts before the update.

Comment: Time to dust off the maps, and do some exploring!

Comment: @John Are you going to be transferring your old map?

Comment: Nah, I think I'll just use this an excuse to go exploring.  I'd hoped to avoid that.  Have a pretty sweet "all in one" farming system built in my current world, but building a witch farm is too darn important....

Comment: Why? Do you want potions?

Comment: @JeffreyLin no, I want glowstone and redstone, and the challenge of building a new Mob farm.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any swamp huts, they will spawn, if not, they won't.

Answer (score -1):

These responses are incorrect, they will spawn in pre pretty scary update worlds. dinner_bone confirmed this somewhere. I used the tool "amidst" which tells you where witch huts should be, and built a witch farm there.

edit: here is my [source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/108s0s/witches_out_of_place/c6bek8g)

and here is AMIDST, perfect for finding witch spawning locations in old worlds. [link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v2042-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-ect-finder-now-with-witch-huts/)

Comment: Please provide information do backup your answer. Specially if you say that all others are wrong...

Comment: If you did it yourself, that's helpful, but not everyone will believe it. If you can find a link to where Dinnerbone said that, that's even better.